# MySQL Union Statement

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask how to join two queries with the only
difference is the where statement. One is with `WHERE c.transac_type = 0` and the other is `WHERE c.transac_type = 1"`.

I want to see the output of SUM(c.amount) in the condition of WHERE c.transac_type = 0 and WHERE c.transac_type = 1 because they have different output of SUM(c.amount).

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount), d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type = 0 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id ORDER BY SUM(c.amount) DESC
```

Comment: Why not `WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1)` instead of `UNION`??

Comment: mysqli is a wrong tag here

Comment: Just FYI, the terms '[mysql] and "right join"' presently appear in SO 952 times. Compare that with '[mysql] and "left join"' which appear 22935 times... I'm just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sums for the transaction types in two different columns, then you want to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount) as totAmount,
       sum(case when c.transac_type = 0 then c.amount end) as Trans0_Amount,
       sum(case when c.transac_type = 1 then c.amount end) as Trans1_Amount,
       d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id
ORDER BY SUM(c.amount) DESC
```

Comment: OMG! This what I exactly need. Thanks for the help. Already using it :) and works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just use `IN(0,1)` instead of union.

try this

```
    SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount), d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id,c.transac_type  ORDER BY SUM(c.amount) DESC
```

Comment: I want to see the output of SUM(c.amount) in the condition of WHERE c.transac_type = 0 and WHERE c.transac_type = 1 because they have different output of SUM(c.amount)

Comment: then add `c.transac_type` in group by check my  updated answer

Comment: Is it possible that I can separate a column for SUM(c.amount) for WHERE c.transac_type = 0 and another column for SUM(c.amount) for WHERE c.transac_type = 1.

Comment: it will be grouped by c.transac_type and then it will be different sum of each

Comment: if you didnt get result , move `c.transac_type` to first place in GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

UNIONing it would be fairly simple, but not sure it would give you useful values

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount) AS AmountSum, d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type = 0 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id 
UNION
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount) AS AmountSum, d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type = 1 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id 
ORDER BY AmountSum DESC
```

You could just get the sum for both transac types

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount) AS AmountSum, d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1) 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id 
ORDER BY AmountSum DESC
```

Or the sums for both of the separately

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(c.amount) AS AmountSum, d.category, e.branch_commission , c.transac_type
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1) 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id, c.transac_type
ORDER BY AmountSum DESC
```

Nasty way of putting both counts on the same line:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.branch_code, SUM(IF(c.transac_type=0,c.amount, 0)) AS AmountSumTransac_0, SUM(IF(c.transac_type=1, c.amount, 0)) AS AmountSumTransac_1, d.category, e.branch_commission 
FROM control_panel_client_create AS a
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_h AS b ON a.id = b.branch_code_id 
    RIGHT JOIN sales_add_i AS c ON b.id = c.sales_h_id 
    RIGHT JOIN control_panel_item_create AS d ON c.item_code_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN control_panel_client_create AS e ON b.branch_code_id = e.id
    WHERE c.transac_type IN (0, 1) 
GROUP BY d.category, b.branch_code_id
ORDER BY AmountSum DESC
```

Comment: I want to see the output of SUM(c.amount) in the condition of WHERE c.transac_type = 0 and WHERE c.transac_type = 1 because they have different output of SUM(c.amount) –

Comment: The last query should do that (added c.transac_type to the GROUP BY, and also changed the check for it to an IN).

Comment: Is it possible that I can separate a column for SUM(c.amount) for WHERE c.transac_type = 0 and another column for SUM(c.amount) for WHERE c.transac_type = 1

Comment: Not really with any efficiency. Could be done in a nasty way (will add code to answer for that)